# Automatically place "+" between every variable

Tags: python

I want to be able to type a giving sequence of 4 letters without placing a "+" between every letter. As shown below i need additional code at the "Input = A+T+C" line so that I can type "Input = ATC" instead.

```
X = "V"
B = "N"
R = "Q"
L = "H"
Input = A+T+C
print("Result " + Input + ",")
```

Comment: You are looking for [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

Comment: Or maybe `str.translate` and using a dictionary to translate one string into another. You can't use `ATC` to get `A+T+C` automatically because `ATC` is a perfectly valid variable name itself (you could do `ATC = "foo"` or whatever).